# Data Toggle image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<a href="#demo1"  data-toggle="collapse"><h3 style="color:#0F77CD;">Form</h3></a>
<div id="demo1" class="collapse">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Capsules" /><br /><br />
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" Text="Combo Pack" /><br /><br />
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" Text="Kit" /><br /><br />
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" Text="Gel" /><br /><br />
</div>
```

The above code is to toggle between the div what I need is I want to add toggle image like minus and plus.When the toggle is expanded it should show minus icon and if collapsed it should show plus icon.

Comment: i usually use this one https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Comment: I too taken it from w3schools but I need icon toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution using `bootstrap v3` https://jsfiddle.net/tyrt75q6/1/

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  if($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-plus')){
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
  } else {
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
  }
});
```

```css
h3 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#demo1"  data-toggle="collapse">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h3 style="color:#0F77CD;">Form</h3> 
</a>
<div id="demo1" class="collapse">
  <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Capsules" /><br /><br />
  <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" Text="Combo Pack" /><br /><br />
  <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" Text="Kit" /><br /><br />
  <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" Text="Gel" /><br /><br />
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It works very well but I need a minus Icon before Form @shiladitya

Comment: @SatG_shanu Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/tyrt75q6/1/